# Python how to create sublists in a loop

Tags: python

I have a python question about the following code block.
The expected output is a sublist, containing the name that is entered into the list, turn it into a gmail account and add a username that only shows the first 4 letters of the input. I currently have this code:

```
def database(L):
    
    result = []
        
        for i in L:
            username = i[0:4]
            result.append(i + '@gmail.com')
            result.append(username)
    
        return result

accounts = database(['Bakerfield', 'Thomas']) 
print(accounts)
```

I currently get the output

```
['Bakerfield@gmail.com', 'Bake' , 'Thomas@gmail.com', 'Thom']
```

But I would like the output:

```
[['Bakerfield@gmail.com', 'Bake'], ['Thomas@gmail.com', 'Thom']]
```

This is because i am not using sublists, and I am unsure how to divide this function loop into one that creates a sublist out of these accounts and essentially seperates these lists.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Just append the list in the same `.append` call like this: `result.append([i + '@gmail.com', username])`

Comment: `result.append([i + '@gmail.com', username])`…

Answer (score 2):

Just do one append, but with a list:

```py
def database(L):
    result = []
        
    for i in L:
        username = i[0:4]
        result.append([i + '@gmail.com', username])
    
    return result
```

Output as required.

Answer (score 0):

Your only issue is which the result.append section. Take a look at this revised code:

```
def database(L):
    
    result = []
        
        for i in L:
            username = i[0:4]
            result.append([i + '@gmail.com'])
            result.append([username])
    
        return result

accounts = database(['Bakerfield', 'Thomas']) 
print(accounts)
```

Notice that you just forgot a single pair of brackets when using the append() function, this should fix it permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dataclass for this. also, only one `append` required after instantiation.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class UsrEmial:
    email: str
    naem: str


def database(L):
    result = []

    for i in L:
        username = i[0:4]
        e_obj_for_usr = UsrEmial(f'{i}@gmail.com', username)
        result.append(e_obj_for_usr)
        # not do:
            # result.append(username)
        # reasoning: `UsrEmial` object contains already this info.

        # here not do (2) appends, instead using only one (1) as above:
            # result.append(i + '@gmail.com')
            # result.append(username)
        # reasoning: two appends will add to list but at the same level,
        # such that 1st and 2nd append result will be as siblings with
        # all the others in a list.
    return result


accounts = database(['Bakerfield', 'Thomas'])
print(accounts)

# OK
assert accounts[-1].naem == 'Thomas'[0:4]
```

Out:

```
[UsrEmial(email='Bakerfield@gmail.com', naem='Bake'), UsrEmial(email='Thomas@gmail.com', naem='Thom')]
```